# Appropriate Syntax For Alternating Row Colors

Tags: colors, row, rdlc, alternating

I am using this code:

```
=IIF(RunningValue(Fields!cost_center_id.Value, CountDistinct, nothing) Mod 2, "White", "Gainsboro")
```

But its result is not good. I think it's because of *Fields!cost_center_id.Value*. Can anybody tell me the most appropriate code?
And why the footer (Total) has also shade thought I haven't put code in it? Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I used this code for the 3rd picture.

```
= IIF(RowNumber("LCSRDBDataSet_CostCenterSummary") Mod 2 = 0, "White", "Gainsboro")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason your expression doesn't work is because your id values might have gaps or not be ordered correctly.

One of these following expressions should give the wanted behavior.

`= IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "White", "Gainsboro")`

`= IIF(RowNumber("YourDataSet") Mod 2 = 0, "White", "Gainsboro")`

You need to define the expression for the `BackgroundColor`property of the *data row*. The footer row (total) should be below the data row, and thus have no expression for it's background color, unless you want it to be different to the final row.

Comment: Then why did it turn out like that? (see new photo attached above) @Oceans

Comment: I can't tell... You're not hiding any rows or filtering the dataset are you? Perhaps try the first expression, using `Nothing` instead of the dataset. If that still doesn't work, can you add a  screenshot of the designer?

Comment: HI @Oceans, what designer?

Comment: I've added a screenshot (bottom part). Is that what you're saying? @Oceans